# How to add additional query parameters in cms page content api call

Tags: spartacus-storefront

we want to append the cms page content api used out of box by spartacus for cart page

current: cms/pages?pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=/cart

required to add some additional query parameter

required: cms/pages?pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=/cart&**staticstorecode=42**

what code changes are required to achieve the above scenario?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page request is made in the `load` method of the `OccCmsPageAdapter`. You would need to override this method to add your additional params. You could extend this class and create your own `CustomOccCmsPageAdapter` and subsequent classes like `CustomPage` model etc.